# Java Hash Multi Map (key with multiple values) Implementation

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, colt, trove4j

From [here](http://b010.blogspot.it/2009/05/speed-comparison-of-1-javas-built-in.html), I found that Colt's `OpenIntIntHashMap` and Trove's `TIntIntHashMap` give better performance and memory uses than Java's built in `HashMap` or Guava's `HashMultimap`.

Do Colt's `OpenIntIntHashMap` or Trove's `TIntIntHashMap` allow keys with multiple values, as with `HashMultimap`? If not what is a nice way to implement a `HashMultimap` that can achieve Colt's or Trove's performance and memory efficiency?

Note: I have tested Guava's `HashMultimap`, but its performance and memory efficiency seems poor to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Multimaps.newSetMultimap(
  TDecorators.wrap(new TIntObjectHashMap<Collection<Integer>>()),
  new Supplier<Set<Integer>>() {
    public Set<Integer> get() {
      return TDecorators.wrap(new TIntHashSet());
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. But, for using this structure what should I have to do ? Means, is Trove has any .jar file ?

Comment: If you go to the Trove website and go to the "Downloads" section it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I download trove from http://sourceforge.net/projects/trove4j/files/trove/3.0.1/. However, when I add trove.jar file in my class path, it gives error that gnu.trove.set.hash.TIntHashSet (and others) are not found. Can you kindly help me, how to use Trove.

Comment: The `trove-3.0.1.jar` file is in the `lib` folder of the zip file.  If adding that to your classpath doesn't help, I can't help you.